# occur NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, linux, camera

I try test usb camera preview on raspberry android.

first, my raspberry pi is arm processor.

and usb camera not problem device.

after I checked occur `NullPointerException` , try null check

`Log.d(TAG,"Camera is connected?"+camera);`
result is `Camera is connected?null`

so, I think `raspberry pi` is 
it seems unable to detect.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
     Camera camera;
     SurfaceView surfaceView;
     SurfaceHolder surfacehHolder;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     .
     .
     getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

     surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
     surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
     surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     }

     @Override
     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

     camera = Camera.open();
     camera.stopPreview();
     Camera.Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
     param.setRotation(90);
     camera.setParameters(param);

     try {
         camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
         camera.startPreview();
     } catch {
        return;
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
       refreshCamera();
  }

  @Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
       camera.stopPreview();
       camera.release();
       camera = null;
  }

  public void refreshCamera() {
      if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() = null) {
         return ;
      } 
      try {
          camera.stopPreview();
      } catch {
      }
  }
 }
```

this code success work in different device. (not raspberry pi)
but only raspberry pi device , occur exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.hardware.Camera.stopPreview()' on a null object reference
at kr.c004245.dom.camera_raspberry_preview.MainActivity.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:134)
at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)
at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2063)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6023)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5488)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:746)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
```

perhaps, raspberry pi android different camera open?
if you know. please advice for me

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for `Camera` say:

> This class was deprecated in API level 21.
>
> We recommend using the new `android.hardware.camera2` API for new applications.

And the javadoc for `open()` says:

> Creates a new Camera object to access the first back-facing camera on the device. **If the device does not have a back-facing camera, this returns null.**

So there are a number of possible explanations:

- Your device does not have a **back-facing** camera.
- Your device's back-facing camera is somehow misconfigured at the OS level on your Raspberry Pi ... to the extent that Android can't find it, or can't use it.
- This deprecated API is not properly implemented on Raspberry Pi Android.

I recommend that you do what the javadoc says, and recode to use the `camera2` APIs.  Then proceed to debug *that*.

If you *cannot* use the `camera2` APIs, then you may need to use `getNumberOfCameras` and `getCameraInfo(...)` to figure out which camera to use, then call `open(ID)` to open the selected camera.  (Actually, just calling and displaying `getNumberOfCameras` would be helpful.)

**UPDATE**

After some more digging, I think the answer is that camera support on an Android Raspberry Pi is pretty rough.  For example:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/android-rpi/camera%7Csort:relevance/android-rpi/7jR_ER1pCbA/xTKg06KUAQAJ

Comment: thanks, but I know use `android.hardware.camera` is more than API level 21 ,  raspberry pi android is never use `android.hardware.camera` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: you say try use `android.hardware.camera2` API  is right?

Comment: I do.  However, I suspect it won't help; see my UPDATE.

Comment: thanks, I checked your answer. so  result, it very hard problem. so I use  (https://apkpure.com/usb-camera/com.shenyaocn.android.usbcamera) this ? is right?

Comment: I have no idea.  Why don't you try it?

Comment: I task raspberry pi, but I familiar android.  so I try raspberry pi android

Comment: My point was this.  Rather than asking someone else if something is "right", try it out for yourself.  I have said that I don't know.